# To split on the basis of space and special character in python

Tags: python, regex

v=vi nod-u

i want to split this string to obtain

l=[vi],[nod],[u]

l.split(" ") splits on the basis of space.

And i dont know the usage of the regular expression import functions properly.
Could anyone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to split the string to get words?  If so, try the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\W+')
>>> pattern.split('vi nod-u')
['vi', 'nod', 'u']
```